# flutter - loading data for search delegate searching list

Tags: flutter

I'm using search delegate in flutter project. I'm getting data from an api then insert them into some list to make search suggestions. The api url is working fine. The data is loaded successfully as you will see in the `getProductsData()` function and added to the dynamic list `products`. But when I print the products data in the constructor after loading it, it prints empty list. I dont know why  is that happening. Here is the code sample:

```
class searchProducts extends SearchDelegate<String>{

  List<dynamic> products = [];

  searchProducts(){
    getProductsData();
    print("Data in the constructor");
    print(products);
  }

  Future getProductsData() async{
    var d = await http.get("http://mahmoudhelal.atwebpages.com/api/e-commerce_apis/products_api.php?fbclid=IwAR3fsifA0DO0KdhKDTke7wnVQANRy9wd9cgmmoypubXaZuQVDBNXC6Wlf5U");
    var jsonData = json.decode(d.body);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonData.length; i++){
      print("before adding "+ jsonData[i]['name']);
      products.add(jsonData[i]['name']);
      print("After adding "+ products[i]);
    }

  }


  List<dynamic> history = [ 'h1', 'h2', 'h3' ];

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: (){
          query = "nothing";
        },

      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      tooltip: 'Back',
      icon: AnimatedIcon(
        icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
        progress: transitionAnimation,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        //Take control back to previous page
        this.close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Returned");
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {


    List<dynamic> suggestionList = query.isEmpty? history : products.where((element) => element.startsWith(query));
    return ListView.builder( itemCount: suggestionList.length,itemBuilder: (context, index){
      return ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.favorite),
        title: Text(suggestionList[index]),
      );
    });


  }
  
}
```

Comment: Hi, print("After adding "+ products[i]); this need a ['name'] ?

Comment: I dont understand your question. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

No, the list will always be empty in the constructor. try to display it in

```
@override
Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    print(products.toString());
   return Text("Returned");
}
```

Comment: Still same problem. Actually I noticed this problem because build suggestions method gives me an error that the list is null.